# Typescript: dynamic list from tuple array without an intersection

Tags: typescript, vue.js

```
const intents = ["primary", "secondary", "accent", "danger"] as const;
const buttonSizes = ["small", "medium", "big"] as const;
type IntentType = (typeof intents)[number];
type SizeType = (typeof buttonSizes)[number];

type ButtonProps = {
  intent?: IntentType;
  size?: SizeType;
} & {
  [K in IntentType as `${Lowercase<K>}`]?: boolean;
};
```

in this code I want a Vue component to be able to receive properties like

or
like

now, if I write the code more statically, like:

```
type ButtonProps = {
  intent?: "primary" | "secondary" | "accent" | "danger";
  size?: "small" | "medium" | "big";
  primary?: boolean;
  secondary?: boolean;
  accent?: boolean;
  danger?: boolean;
}
```

it works.... but then I have some other code that needs to iterate over the intent options, and just make it repeating all the time...

the first example works, but for some reason VUE throws an error

> Internal server error: [@vue/compiler-sfc] type argument passed to
> defineProps() must be a literal type, or a reference to an interface
> or literal type.

The [bug seems to be known](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4294) and is being addressed, so it seems

What would be the other way to define more dynamically the ButtonProps without using the intersection?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the error says "reference to an interface or literal type", I'm under the assumption that defining `ButtonProps` as an interface extending a base type should work:

```
type IntentAndSize = {
  [K in IntentType as `${Lowercase<K>}`]?: boolean;
};

interface ButtonProps extends IntentAndSize {
  intent?: IntentType;
  size?: SizeType;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmKBTREYF4YG0BEAHAJzgFsBDAgTxwBoYcIlQwATcq2nU4YFKGu1mADmSAjgC6MUmibQA3AFgAULNgAjAK5Qo4AMpwAXkjSZcEMgBsL-HMSTM4G4jbVwhEqTPDzlUCniQYAElEXgAVf0DMAAo-AJAAM3hQ1ABKLDAnNVFxRSU4wP0jCICMGFjIxJhNbT1DY3TM4myCXOVfSOCUqABBFiKomABvZRhsAGlkruREEsDpGAADABIhgBkQAHdRYGkkAB5xgD4AX0XxAH4ALmqQEAskUjA8k7zlBGQCBK5AgCEtHRgAAKBBAeDQSAAHjNmGgQjNev16sNRskEddpuFInkxhB6hiBnMXkA)

Comment: tried that already, but in this case I am getting a weird error

`Default export of the module has or is using private name`

Comment: In the playground, I can see it works, but in vue, it clearly doesn't :'( only intent and size properties are being picked up